# changing a label on a panel at the bottom of my JFrame puts text at the top

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame with two panels.  The top panel is for displaying graphics.  The bottom panel is for displaying status.  The two panels are different colors.  When I try to change the text of JLabels on the bottom panel, it creates text at the top of the top panel.  How do I change my code so it only shows on the bottom.  Here is the code:

```
public void setManInfo(String manNews) {
        manInfo.setText(manNews);
    }
```

manInfo is my JLabel.  It is on the panel with a GridBagLayout.

Comment: In the future, and if you need more help, post a proper [mcve] when you ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

> The top panel is for displaying graphics.
>
> it creates text at the top of the top panel.

Probably because your custom painting is incorrect.

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method of your panel. And don't forget to invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` to make sure the backgrounds get painting properly and you don't have painting artifacts.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.